# How to customize the cast dialogue? is it possible to add media player timer slider there without using expandedview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chromecast

I am integrating google cast in my application but doesn't work for me as 
`[GCKCastContext sharedInstance].useDefaultExpandedMediaControls = YES;` 
 is used in appdelegate but it popped  **no visible @interface for GCKCastContext** Is there any way to add player timer slider on the cast dialogue or what is my problem in using in default ExpandedMediaControls? 
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate) to know how to integrate Cast in the iOS App. There is a content here that can tell you on how to [add Expanded Controller](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_integrate#add_expanded_controller) properly. It includes sample code that can serve as a guide for you. For more information, check also this Internal: [GCKCastContext Class](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_cast_context)

Comment: Thanks! @KENdi  **Finally solved** : With updating cocoapods file as,  ` pod 'google-cast-sdk', '~> 3.1.1' ` where GCKUIExpandedMediaControlsViewController is included after that  useDefaultExpandedMediaControls is working.

Comment: Glad to hear that